# Can Doctrine2 @OrderBy a calculated field?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to sort my model's associated `ArrayCollection` with a quotient, like this (I know the following code doesn't work):

```
/** 
 * @OneToMany (targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="product") 
 * @OrderBy ({"voted_up / voted_down" = "DESC"})
 */
protected $reviews;
```

Is something this possible directly in the model definition or do I need to simply use a sort() on the `ArrayCollection` when requesting the data?

Comment: Are you seriously using a field name as "voted_up / voted_down" as a name?  I do not want to be judgemental. But I think it is some sort of abobination.

Comment: Sorry, no. To clarify, it's a calculation. "voted_up" is an int field, and "voted_down" is an int field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Doctrine 2.1 you can do that directly in the model definition, but not with @OrderBy. You can define DQL snippets at model level, like stated in the [2.1 Beta release notes](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-1-beta-release):

*Named DQL Queries in Metadata: You can add dql queries in the mapping files using @NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="foo", query="DQL")) and access them through $em->getRepository()->getNamedQuery().*

As such you can create your DQL query with the ORDER BY keywords, something like:

```
SELECT c.id, c.text, (c.voted_up / c.voted_down) AS sortkey FROM Comment c
ORDER BY sortkey DESC
```

So, I imagine you add this annotation to the model definition, something like:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="comment")
 * @NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="sortedComment", query="SELECT c.id, c.text, (c.voted_up / c.voted_down) AS sortkey FROM Comment c ORDER BY sortkey DESC"))
 */
 class Comment {
     ...
 }
```

And then on your code call:

```
$em->getRepository("Comment")->getNamedQuery("sortedComment");
```

I didn't test this, but you get the idea.

Comment: That's great news!  I'm still using 2.0, so I will hack a solution while I wait for a stable 2.1.  Thanks so much for your answer, faken!