# Doctrine2 complex ordering

Tags: doctrine-orm

I've got a comments table, and each comment has a status like "approved", "awaiting moderation", "hidden". When I show the comments I want them to be sorted according to their statuses - "approved", then "awaiting moderation", then "hidden". I can do that with UNIONs but that's a poor solution performance-wise.

I wonder if there's a Doctrine2 equivalent for "ORDER BY (status <> 'hidden') DESC"? I know about ordering by calculated fields ( [Can Doctrine2 @OrderBy a calculated field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246311/can-doctrine2-orderby-a-calculated-field)) but I don't see how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you resolve this issue?  Another way you can do it, is do an sql query by where you give values to the status, and order by that if you want.

$conn = $entity_manager->getConnection();
  $stmt = $conn->query("
      select 
         d.*, case status when 'approved' then 1 
                          when 'awaiting moderation' then 2
                          when 'hidden' then 3 end sequence
      from table order by sequence
   ");

Just loop threw them.

Comment: Sorry, been away for some time. I'm familiar with this workaround, but this way you only get a set of arrays as a result, and I'd like to have my model instances. The solution I came up with is quering a MySQL view (instead of my initial table) where all the records are sorted properly. Not the most flexible one, but works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `CASE` expression and a `HIDDEN` keyword if you're using 2.2:

As of [Doctrine CaseExpression EBNF](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions), you can use

`SELECT
c,
CASE WHEN (c.status = 'hidden') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HIDDEN sortValue
FROM
Comment c
ORDER BY
sortValue DESC`

Comment: Actually, I'm still on 2.1 and updating vendors is not an options right now. But I'll keep this in mind, thank you.